# How to find similarity between two text columns in a csv

Tags: nlp, sentence-similarity

I have two text columns in a csv file with 4000 records.I have to perform text similairty between two text columns.How can I do it?

Comment: This is too broad a question. Please add some details such as your definition or context of similarity (syntactic/semantic/etc.) and the tools you have in hand (software, programming languages you know, etc.) then we can try to answer. Other than that, it's a full academic course!

Comment: Check this blog post to have an idea: https://nlp.town/blog/sentence-similarity/

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it by training one of your columns from csv with the below pip package and pass the other column as input to measure the sentence similarity.

```
pip install similar-sentences
```